# Why does the debugger hit the default case?

Tags: c#, debugging, switch-statement

Some colleague ran into a very strange debugging issue in which he steps through a switch, steps to some case but yet afterwards it hits the default case as well. I have no idea how that can ever happen!

It's easily reproducible and I finally have extracted the code into a small test.

If I put a breakpoint on the default case only, then the debugger will never stop there. But If I add a breakpoint at case 42, and then use step over, it will hit the default case afterwards!!
Remark that the catch is never reached though. So it seems that the debugger is showing something that is not actually happening?
Also, if I remove the async task and await, then it will not happen..
We also need another case that declares a variable (something fancy, not a simple integer etc..)

```
public class Foo
{
    public readonly string Bar = nameof(Bar);
}

public async Task DoSomething(int x)
{
    try
    {
       switch (x)
       {
            case 43:
                var foo = new Foo();
                break;     
            case 42:
                Console.WriteLine(x);
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("aaarghh..");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
    }
}

private async void btnSomethingTo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await DoSomething(42);
}
```

GIF created by Sinatr to illustrate the topic on hand, thanks!
[image: the issue onhand]

Comment: Did you compile as Debug or as Release? Does the `NotImplementedException` actually get thrown?

Comment: I did compile as debug, and the NotImplementedException  is not even thrown! Btw, when running as release, the default case is never hit

Comment: Seems more like debugger isn´t able to show the current statement properly.

Comment: Are you sure that your code built correctly? That is, might you be debugging an old exe, and the code has changed since it was built?

Comment: You could have added an empty line, without compilation, and start an older version, than the line numbering gets a little confused. You could check on disassembly, where you really are. There are so many information to keep in sync, it works (just alsmost) perfect.

Comment: I am 100% sure that it is correctly built. The code I copied here, is the code that I actually tried to debug this issue.

Comment: @Erwin_H Just check: change something important, like change the `Console.WriteLine` to write something else, then run it again. Check that the update is reflected in what your application prints

Comment: I have tried several times already, so the code has changed a lot. Btw, we also have this on our actual program with totally different code..

Comment: I believe it is somehow related to the fact that in Debug mode switch statement is compiled to the if-else statement (rather than jump table in Release mode). So instead of hitting last curly brace after break; statement it hits last line which is default.

Comment: @Erwin_H Right, but that doesn't guarantee that the latest change actually *built*. I'm asking you to change something small, but which you can verify has been compiled by looking at the program's output.

Comment: Yeah, you could remove default case and call DoSomething(43). It will still "hit" the last line - the break of 42 case.

Comment: @AlexanderGoldabin, actually now you mention it. If I move another case at the end, then it will indeed hit the break of that case

Comment: Ah, no, I've replicated this. It only happens when the `DoSomething` method is `async`. I think the debugger's just confused.

Comment: @canton7, can you add more details of how to reproduce it? wpf? winforms? which VS? framework?

Comment: @Sinatr I managed from a console app, VS2019, .NET 4.7.2. I had to remove the `MessageBox` stuff of course. I just call `DoSomethingAsync` from an async Main.

Comment: Currently using winforms, .net 4.5.1, vs 2017 pro

Comment: I reproduced the same in .NET Core 3 console app, JetBrains Rider.

Comment: I've made a [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTp9P.gif) (feel free to [edit] it into question if you want). So we are talking about that single step when debugger is highlighting line after `default`? It doesn't looks like a *big* issue to me, because it also highlight code blocks (they are not really a code). I would ignore it.

Comment: You are right, that it doesn't seem a big issue. However I am curious to know why this happens. Because at first my colleague thought something was wrong in his code, and he was spending time to find out what. Big thanks for the GIF though!

Comment: Try Rebuild or Clean and Build to force using the new code

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Please read the comments above. We've established that that is *not* the issue here

Answer (score -1):

You have used the **DoSomething** method not in proper way.
**ASYNC** keyword means you have some **await** call somewhere within method (to get return point later after task end),  but you haven't it.
Your strange debugger behavior is related to implementation. Your exception is not thrown by fact. I have reproduced your case and **MyException** constructor is just ignored/skipped by debugger, and the code in **catch (Exception exc)** section is never called too. Or if I am got break within **CASE 42:** and I just press F5, then my breakpoint within DEFAULT section will be skipped.

```
public async Task DoSomething(int x)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (x)
                {
                    case 43:
                        var foo = new Foo();
                        break;
                    case 42:
                        Debug.WriteLine(x);
                        break;
                    case 44:
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new MyException("aaarghh..");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await DoSomething(42);
        }

        public class MyException : Exception
        {
            public MyException(string message): base(message)
            {
                if (message != null)
                    Debug.WriteLine(message);
            }

            public MyException() : base()
            {
            }

            public MyException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Okay, I can add an async method in the DoSomething, but that is irrelevant to the question

Comment: Regardless to debugger stepping you have code with proper behavior. In Debug window you will have only "42" but not "aaarghh.."

Comment: I still reproduce this even if I `await` inside `DoSomething`. Yes it's related to the debugger being confused by the code generated for an `async` method, I think, but it's nothing to do with whether there's an `await` inside `DoSomething`

Comment: @canton7 yes, I did want to say that the ASYNC keyword in method declaration may confuse the debugger's  visualizer, not the CLR (because we can see in Errors Window  that the compiler warning about that the DoSomething will be ran synchronously due to lack of AWAIT call within itself)

Comment: You said "*You have used the DoSomething method not in proper way*" -- I don't think "not in the proper way" has anything to do with it, is my point

Comment: I said "You have used the DoSomething method not in proper way" exactly for explain possible cause of debugger visualizer behavior, because what you see in Editor not direct reflect the actual call stack etc, and many typical cases are just hardcoded to give to end-user intuitive experience. This case may just not workarounded yet so we can see this strange hitting the default section, but in low level we actually not in that place

Comment: The point is, I can update the question and add an awaitable method in there. Then still the behavior is the same, and your answer does not add any new insights. I already found out that the code is not actually executed. (see OP "So it seems that the debugger is showing something that is not actually happening?")